# Request are not being mapped in spring boot using embedded tomcat

Tags: spring, rest, spring-boot, tomcat

I have started a new REST spring boot application using MySQL but I am not able to register user using postman and unable to map them

I am using STS 4.3.1,
xampp for MySQL,
I have seen every example for creating REST services.

//my entry point

```
package com.accounts.rtgsneft;


@SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages = {"com.account.rtgsneft.controllers","com.account.rtgsneft.dao","com.account.rtgsneft.models","com.account.rtgsneft.services"})
public class RtgsNeftApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(RtgsNeftApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

//my controller

```
@CrossOrigin(origins = "*", maxAge = 3600)
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/")

public class EmployeeController {
    @Autowired
    private EmployeeService employeeService;



    @PostMapping("/register")
    public ResponseEntity<?> RegisterControl(@RequestBody EmployeeMaster employee) {
        System.out.println("here:");
        try {
            employee = employeeService.Register(employee);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }

        return ResponseEntity.ok(employee);
    }

    @RequestMapping("/error")
    public void getError() {
        System.out.println("error caught");
    }

}
```

//my model

```
@Component
@Entity
@Table(name = "users")
public @Getter @Setter class EmployeeMaster {

    @Id
    private Long empNumber;
    private String empName;
    private String username;
    private String empPassword;
    private String email;
    private String branch;
    private String role;

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "EmployeeMaster [empNumber=" + empNumber + ", empName=" + empName + ", username=" + username
                + ", empPassword=" + empPassword + ", email=" + email + ", branch=" + branch + ", role=" + role + "]";
    }


}
```

//my Repository

```
package com.accounts.rtgsneft.repositories;

@Repository
public interface EmployeeRepository extends JpaRepository<EmployeeMaster, String> {

}
```

//my service interface and class

```
package com.accounts.rtgsneft.sevices;


public interface EmployeeService {


    public EmployeeMaster Register(EmployeeMaster employeeMaster);
}


package com.accounts.rtgsneft.sevices;


@Component
public class EmployeeServiceImpl implements EmployeeService {

    @Autowired
    private EmployeeRepository employeeRepo;
    @Override
    public EmployeeMaster Register(EmployeeMaster employeeMaster) {

        return employeeRepo.save(employeeMaster);
    }



}
```

//my application.properties

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/rtgs_neft?useSSL=false&useTimezone=true&serverTimezone=UTC
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=
spring.jpa.show-sql=true

spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect

spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto = update

server.port= 8080
```

//console

```
2019-08-08 17:06:28.132  INFO 9584 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat started on port(s): 8080 (http) with context path ''
  2019-08-08 17:06:28.134  INFO 9584 --- [           main] c.accounts.rtgsneft.RtgsNeftApplication  : Started RtgsNeftApplication in 3.706 seconds (JVM running for 4.289)
    2019-08-08 17:06:59.576  INFO 9584 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring DispatcherServlet 'dispatcherServlet'
    2019-08-08 17:06:59.576  INFO 9584 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Initializing Servlet 'dispatcherServlet'
    2019-08-08 17:06:59.600  INFO 9584 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Completed initialization in 24 ms
```

there is no error on console the servlet is dispatched successfully.
but i am not able to post my data on servlet when i use postman to post the request on

```
localhost:8080/employee/register
```

Comment: Do you get an exception or an error message?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The endpoint you are trying to hit was not configured properly.
Please replace the root `@RequestMapping("/")`
with `@RequestMapping("/employee")`.
Now hit this endpoint `localhost:8080/employee/register` it will work.